# Visual Studio Code keeps crashing while working

Tags: visual-studio-code

My visual studio code seems fine and all of the sudden boom its crashed. Searched google for the error code No solution found. Any help would be appreciated.
error code = -536870904

Comment: You didn't say what OS you are using, so I am guessing it is Windows.  Now -536870904 is E00000008.  So that might be Windows error code 8 which means "out of memory"; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-.  So solutions might be to close other applications (that are using lots of memory), get more RAM or increase the size of the page file.

Comment: If it is because of memory then it may be because Local Events is running too many programs at once. Try to close all background programs or upgrade your machine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever anything stops working for no apparent reason then think:

Did it work before?

- No, it is new or it has not worked yet.

  - Check your download, ensure it is compatible with your operating system and other running programs.
- Yes, it used to work, but now it doesn't.

  - Look at the next step

Did you recently update the program, your operating system or any other programs?

- Yes, I updated something.

  - Try rolling back your updates to see if it works again. New versions of software tend to be more error prone than the older, established versions.
- No, I don't think I changed anything.

  - Either you are unaware of changes made to your system or some subscription has ran out. At this phase, the best option is to use common sense or uninstall and reinstall.

Another issue that you might be having is if you're running too many programs at once and your computer is force closing programs to protect itself. Try monitoring your Task Manager you may see a spike right before the crash. Also, make sure the crash isn't caused because of trying to run code (especially with code that has infinite loops)